# A customer sent me an Email with a digital signature. How can I send him an encrypted Email using Outlook now?

Tags: encryption, email, microsoft-outlook

So this customer asked me to send me an encrypted Email. For that he sent the Email with his Digital Signature.
I trusted the certificate that was contained and I also know I can get the public key from it that.
But how can I send him an encrypted email (with attachment) using his public key in Outlook 2013?

Comment: Do you already have a certificate for your own? And consider looking at this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Encrypt-email-messages-373339cb-bf1a-4509-b296-802a39d801dc

Comment: No, actually I dont. When I try the method described in the link I get a message saying that `Microsoft Outlook cannot sign or encrypt this message because there are no certificates which can be used to send from the email address xx@yy.zz`

Comment: This error tells you that you need a certificate for your email address. Do you want to encrypt using S/MIME?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer using S/MIME.

Comment: So your customer has signed his e-mail using S/MIME aswell?

Comment: Exactly. S/MIME using SHA1 and RSA 2048.

Comment: You cannot encrypt an email with your customers public key.  You need your own private key